# sometimes chrome's hot key not work in my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, browser

In my website, sometimes I cannot use any hot key.What's more, right clicking show no menu. But it works in other website!
All those work again if I close my browser and reopen it.

chrome's version is  38.0.2125.111, mac os

Comment: Your webpage must be intercepting right click events (and keyboard clicks). Check for javascript errors clicking F12 and opening the "Console" tab.

Comment: there are no exception in the console.